# CLR Function Exception : The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, database-project

I am trying to call a asmx web service form SQL server 2008 R2, I used WSDL.exe to generate the proxy, and I target framework 3.5.  I used Visual studio 2008 to create a database project.   I add a reference to System.Web.Services to project references.  assembly version match the version in the GAC of database server (2.0.50727.3053).

The assembly appears to be installed correctly and I used UNSAFE PermissionSet.   When I tried to execute the CLR functions I got the exception below.  What are chances?

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "InstalledFunc": 
System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
   at Net..ctor()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart SQL server instance to fix the problem